# How do I output a single value from a dataframe to a CSV?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am trying to get a single value from a dataframe into a CSV file.  I am trying to get information on MLB statistics and used the attached function to extract the data from MLB.com after doing some scraping.  However, I only want the first row (and ideally just the team name) to be extracted to a separate CSV file.  From the output below, I only want to return "Toronto Blue Jays".

```
import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

import random
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='filepath/chromedriver')

 driver.get('http://www.mlb.com')

 stats_header_bar = driver.find_element_by_class_name('megamenu-navbar-overflow__menu-item--stats')

 stats_header_bar.click()

 stats_line_items = stats_header_bar.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

 stats_line_items[2].click()

 hitting_season_element = 
 driver.find_element_by_id('st_hitting_season')
 season_select = Select(hitting_season_element)
 season_select.select_by_value('2015')

 wait = wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

 team_hr_stats = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'datagrid')))

 print('The HR dropdown in the header was loaded successfully. The mouse will move over the element after a short delay')
 normal_delay = random.normalvariate(2, 0.5)
 print('Sleeping for {} seconds'.format(normal_delay))
 time.sleep(normal_delay)
 print('Now moving mouse...')
 ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(team_hr_stats).perform()

 team_hr_total = team_hr_stats.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')

 team_hr_total[10].click()

 data_div_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('datagrid')
 data_html_1 = data_div_1.get_attribute('innerHTML')

 import bs4
 import requests

 soup_1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data_html_1, 'html5lib')


def extract_stats_data(data_element):
    data_html = data_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data_html, 'html5lib')

    column_names = [t.text.replace('▼', ' ').replace('▲', ' ').strip() 
    for t in soup.thead.tr.findAll('th')]

    row_lists = []
    for row in soup.tbody.findAll('tr'):
        row_lists.append([col.text for col in row.findAll('td')])

    df = pd.DataFrame(row_lists, columns=column_names)

    numeric_fields = ['HR']
    for field in numeric_fields:
        df[field] = pd.to_numeric(df[field])

    return df

df = extract_stats_data(data_div_1)

df.to_csv('Filename.csv')
```

[image]

Comment: So what does your data look like in your dataframe and what is your current output?

Comment: I edited my previous post to include the output.

Comment: So you just want the text `Toronto Blue Jays` written to a file?  Also please add the code/url used to create `data_div_1`.

Comment: Correct by exporting the index of the file.  I will need to do this more and want a way to write a specific value.

Comment: I've added the full code I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you have provided shows that the data is sorted by greatest `HR` first. So you first need to sort your `df` the same way:

```
df = extract_stats_data(data_div_1)
team_name = df.sort_values('HR', ascending=False).iloc[0]['Team']  # With highest HR     

# Write team name string to file
with open('Filename.csv', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(team_name)
```